# Find the minimum of a set of data input from the keyboard

Tags: java, methods, pseudocode

I have an algorithm in my textbook written in pseudocode which is then supposed to be "implemented to a Java method". It goes like this:

read min;
while not eoln do
read x
if x < min then
min <- x
end if
end while
print min;

Then I'm given this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

int min() {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("x=? (999 to end)");
int x = input.nextInt();
int min = x;

while (x!=999) {
    System.out.println("x=? (999 to end)");
    x = input.nextInt();
    if (x < min) {
    min = x;
    }
}
return min;
}
```

I put everything below import.Scanner inside of the main method and inside of a class like this:

```
public class MyAlgorithm {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// code here
}
}
```

But then I get this error message in Terminal:

```
MyAlgorithm.java:7: error: ';' expected
int min() {
           ^
1 error
```

Am I missing something? If I put the semicolon there, the whole thing just won't work.

Comment: That means you got to learn Java!

Comment: Show all your code. It sounds like (but it's unclear that) you inserted the import and the `min` method ***within*** the `main` method. That would explain the problem.

Comment: Are you saying you put the first segment of code inside of the main method? Are you trying to define a function inside of main? I'm unsure what your actual code looks like. If you want to define min you need to do it ouside of main then call it from within main.

Comment: https://ideone.com/tbkvIB

Comment: I have no idea what I'm doing, honestly. Do I understand correctly that the min() part should go into the class? And the loop, too? But when I did that I also got a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your method `min()` inside the `main()` method. In Java, you can not define a method inside a method. In Java, you need an object to call its methods (Except you make the methods static). So your final Code looks something like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyAlgorithm  {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyAlgorithm  m = new MyAlgorithm ();
      m.min();
   }

   int min(){
      //Your min code goes here
      return min_value;
    // min_value is the same as your min variable. It has another name to
    // prevent name collisions
   }
}
```

If you are allowed to use static methods, (which I don't think) you can use the following alternative:

```
static int min(){
    //Your min code goes here
    return min_value;
    // min_value is the same as your min variable. It has another name to
    // prevent name collisions
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int result = MyAlgorithm.min();
}
```

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: @cupoftae I have added example Code that you can refer to

Comment: Ok, I see. I've tried both these structures and they worked. One last (probably stupid) question: does it matter if I return 1 or min?

Comment: @cupoftae yes it matters. You have to return `min`. If you return 1, which was only a placeholder, you will always get 1 as min value, which is definitely not what you want. I'll change it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you put your min method inside of main, this is defining methods from within other methods which will not work properly and cannot compile. The main method is the commands you want to run as soon as you start your program, any other functions in the class should be declared outside of it, and if you want them to run in main you do a method call.

it should look something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyAlgorithm {

    int min() {
    //(min code)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // code here
    //corrected according to Uli's comment
        MyAlgorithm m = new MyAlgorithm();
        int result = m.min();
    }
}
```

I suggest reading up on how java programs are structured. Here's an article on [methods.](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods.asp)

Comment: This won't work because the main method is static. You first need to create an object of MyAlgorithm.

Comment: @UliSotschok You updated your answer right before i posted, now this one is basically restating what you have, I might delete it.

Comment: you are right about putting the min function outside of the main. But the problem in your code is, how you call the min method. This will raise an error when you paste it to your IDE

Comment: I spent too much time working with C, so that mistake slipped past me haha.